# Is there any practical use of "Void" structure in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, void

Just of a curiosity, is there any practical use of "Void" [struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.void_members.aspx)

except in Reflection ?

Comment: It would be cool if we could use it as a type parameter, for a generic class when that type is not needed/relevant. For instance: `public class SomeServiceWithoutResponse : BaseService<MyRequestType, Void>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`System.Void` is the equivalent of the `void` keyword. Check the tool tip of `void` and it will display

> struct System.Void

But it can't be used directly in C#, so you best ignore it.

Trying to use `System.Void` will generate a compilation error

> error CS0673: System.Void cannot be used from C# -- use typeof(void) to get the void type object

So then, it will fall to the topic of reflection only.

Answer (score 3):

I think, but I'm not sure, that this struct is used by the compiler to generate il for functions with void return type

Comment: +1, that's correct.  System.Void can be used as-is in the C++/CLI language.

Answer (score 2):

Well documentation says,

*The Void  structure is used in the System.Reflection  namespace, but is rarely useful in a typical application. The Void structure has no members other than the ones all types inherit from the Object  class.*

So I doubt it.